# printing ASCII codes of characters stored in C-string - explanation needed

Tags: c++, string, pointers, io, c-strings

This program converts the char to their ASCII code
Program works perfectly, but i don't understand how the line `cout << (int) *p1++ << ' ';` works. Еspecially `*p1++` in this inner `while` loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
void main ()
{
    char s[80];
    char *p1;
    do
    {
        p1 = s;

        cout << "Enter the string";
        gets(p1);
        while (*p1) 
        cout << (int) *p1++ << ' ';
        cout << '\n';
    }
    while (strcmp (s, "End"));
 }
```

Comment: Get a book on the language.

Answer (score 4):

```
while (*p1) 
    cout << (int) *p1++ << ' ';
```

means:

- while `p1` points to character value of which is different from 0 (i.e. `'\0'`)

  - obtain the character it points to (`*p1` = dereferencing of pointer `p1`)
  - cast this character to `int` so that ASCII code is outputted (number instead of character)
  - output space after the number that has been just printed
  - increment pointer `p1` to make it point to the next character

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << (int) *p1++ << ' ';
```

Here:

1. The character pointed to by `p1` is converted to an `int` and written to `cout` followed by a single space.
2. `p1` is advanced to point to the next character (this is what `p1++` does).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy :)

while (*p1) => as long as the byte pointed by p1 is not zero....
cout << (int) *p1++ << ' '; => print char pointed by p1 and increment the pointer afterwards. Cast the result (char) into int and print it.

while (*p) {do_somthing(); p++;} is a common way of iterating through a c string.